# Pandas: how to count the frequency of words in a column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file containing 4 columns, where column1 is car_id, column2 is manufacturer, column3 is car_year and column4 is the car model as below. I would like to use pandas dataframe to only count the model in coumn4 if the make in column2 is 'Ford'.

```
column 1    column2   column3   column4
 005         Ford      2012      Mustang
 125         Ford      2020      Focus
 223         BMW       2017      X5
 115         Ford      2015      Focus
 566         Kia       2011      ceed
```

So the output be something like

```
model    counts
Mustang  1
Focus    2
```

Any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select base on `column2` then use `.values_counts()`. try this:

```
>>> df[df['column2'] == 'Ford']['column4'].value_counts()
```

As DataFrame:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df[df['column2'] == 'Ford']['column4'].value_counts()
                ).reset_index()\
.rename(columns={'index':'model', 'column4':'counts'}
)
    model       counts
0   Ford        2
1   Mustang     1
```